# NP-hardness of finding maximum of minimum element in diagonal of a matrix

Tags: co.combinatorics, computational-complexity, combinatorial-optimization, np

For $A = \{a_{ij}\} \in R^{n\times n}$, is finding

$$
\max_{\sigma \in S_n}\min_{1 \le i \le n} a_{i,\ \sigma_i}
$$

NP-hard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be polynomial.  Here is a proof.  It will be convenient to regard $A$ as an edge-weighted complete bipartite graph $G$.  Let $m_1 < \dots < m_\ell$ be the list of edge weights of $G$, let $E_i$ be the set of edges of weight $m_i$, and let $G_i:=G \setminus (E_1 \cup \dots \cup E_i)$.  Now test if $G_1$ has a perfect matching (note this can be done in polynomial-time).  If no, then the answer is $m_1$.  If yes, then test if $G_2$ has a perfect matching and recurse.  If $k$ is the first index such that $G_k$ does not have a perfect matching, then output $m_k$ as the answer.

Comment: Brilliant idea! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: If by "recurse" you meant to increment $k$ by $1$, you might instead see better performance in practice by performing a bisection search on $k$.